# How to transfer character and int value into enum in c#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have defined a Enum as blow, it includes int type and character type.

I tried to parse string into enum, but it would
occur error when input character.

How to fix this?

```
//parse successfully.
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "1"); 

//error:Requested value 'A' was not found.
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "A"); 

 public enum MyEnum
    {
        [Description("Des1")]
        Status1 = 1,
        [Description("Des2")]
        Status2 = 2,
        [Description("Des3")]
        Status3 = 3,
        [Description("Des4")]
        Status4 = 4,
        [Description("Des7")]
        Status5 = 5,
        [Description("Des6")]
        Status6 = 6,
        [Description("Des7")]
        Status7 = 7,
        [Description("Des8")]
        Status8 = 8,
        [Description("Des9")]
        Status9 = 9,
        [Description("DesA")]
        StatusA = 'A',
        [Description("DesB")]
        StatusB = 'B',
        [Description("DesC")]
        StatusC = 'C',
    }
```

Update：

OK, I think I need check the input is digit or not to do different process.
Code as Below did work, thanks for everyone's advise.

```
    string inputParam = "A";
    int useLess;
    MyEnum myEnum;
    var isDigit = int.TryParse(inputParam, out useLess);
    if (isDigit) {
        myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), inputParam);
    }
    else
    {
        myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), ((int)Convert.ToChar(inputParam)).ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the enum is in fact based on `int` values, so the char values are being converted to `int`.

In other words, this:

```
StatusA = 'A',
```

Is actually converted to this:

```
StatusA = 65,
```

Because the actual numeric value of `StatusA` is `65`, you'd have to do:

```
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "65");
```

or alternatively, to make it more obvious that `65` is `'A'`:

```
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), ((int)'A').ToString());
```

Note that `enum.Parse()` will parse either the *name* of the enum member, or a string containing the numeric value of the enum member, so either "65" or "StatusA" would work.

So all of the following lines will return the same result:

```
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "65");
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), ((int)'A').ToString());
MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "StatusA");
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, the code can parse 'A' successfully, but I found '1' would failed, using MyEnum failEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), ((int)Convert.ToChar("1")).ToString()); result would became "49" instead Status1.

Comment: @EvaHHHH So you want a universal way to parse both `"1"` and `"A"`? I don't think that's possible. You'd have to use something like `char.IsDigit` to distinguish between the two cases. If it is not a digit, cast it to the enum as in my answer. Otherwise, if it is a digit, use `char.GetNumericValue` (or subtract `'0'` from it) to convert it to a number, then cast it to the enum. This is all assuming that you know the string to be parsed is valid.

Answer (score 2):

`Enum.Parse` only works for the *names* or the *numeric* values of the associated constant values. of the enum members. `'A'` is neither of those. If you have passed the string `"65"` to the method, it would have worked.

Note that *how* you write the associated constant value doesn't matter - whether it's `'A'`, or `65`, or `0b1000001` or `0x41`, they all look the same to the compiler. `Enum.Parse` only accepts the second way of writing it.

To convert the character `'A'` to the enum type `MyEnum`, you just need a cast:

```
MyEnum foo = (MyEnum)'A';
```

However, since you have a string `"A"` here, you need to get the first character (assuming that you are sure that the string represents one of the associated constant values):

```
MyEnum foo = (MyEnum)"A"[0];
```